# "name:out not defined" - programming error

Tags: python, python-2.6

```
import Image, os, sys 

for filename in sys.argv[1:]: 
 img=Image.open(filename).crop((100,100, 200, 200)) 
 out=file(os.path.splitext(filename)[0]+"/media/New Volume_/sruthy's files nd songs!/PROJECT/scan/mug 002.jpg", "w") 
try: 
 img.save(out, "/media/New Volume_/sruthy's files nd songs!/PROJECT/scan/mug 002.jpg") 
finally: 
 out.close()
```

error as 'name:out not defined'
please help me to correct it. . .

Comment: What line number does it occur at? I'm guessing the last one, but you should still tell us.

Comment: What line number was mentioned? This is very important.  Please indicate which **exact** line is raising the error.

Answer (score 2):

The `save` method takes a filename, not a file object. See the [PIL online documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm).